# installing software package for any user account and root user

Tags: package-management, sudo, root

Suppose I've two users in my system viz. USER1 and USER2.

When I need to install any package for any user say *USER1*, I need to do "**sudo su**" which means *root privilege*. **But is this software installed only for the USER1, though I've done "sudo su"? Why is it so?**

How to install any package in a system that can be accessible to every user in the machine?

Answer (score 5):

Programs installed from the Software Center or `apt-get` should be installed globally (system wide) and will be available to all users.

This is because they are not installed in a particular user's home folder but in the `usr` folder.

Each user will have their own file in their account to save there preferences and data except any user logged in as a guest, as their data is deleted on logging out.

.sh and .bin files that install without `root` will only be available by the user that installed it unless the folder that it is installed in is made available to all users via the sharing options via the mouse right click or the command line `chmod`.  This is because programs that install without `root` **only** install into the home directory of the user that installed them.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204900/are-installed-applications-for-all-users-or-only-for-the-account-who-installed-t/204904#204904)